# PHP regular expression all numbers after last instance of

Tags: regex

Hi I would like to get all numbers after the last instance of - in php

my code is like so at the moment

```
$results = array();       
    $pattern = '/[^\-]*$/';       
    $pattern_no_chars ="[!0-9]";
    preg_match($pattern, $alias_title, $matches);         

    if(count($matches) <1){
        return $results;
    }

    $last_id = end($matches);
    $id_no_char = preg_replace($pattern_no_chars, '', $last_id);
```

For example a url may be /image/view?alias_title=birkenhead-park-15-v-lymm-49-00601jpg-6514

in this case i would want 6514

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use

```
preg_match('~(?<=-)\d+$~',$str,$m);
if (!empty($m)) echo $m[0];
```

Here's the breakdown:

```
(?<=-)  # last character before the match should be a dash
\d+     # 1 or more decimals (aka. the matched part)
$       # end of string
```

And here's an example

```
$str = '/view?alias_title=network-warringtons-optare-versa-hybrid-yj62fkl-102-1593';
preg_match('~(?<=-)\d+$~',$str,$m);
if (!empty($m)) echo $m[0];
```

Finally, here's the output: **`1593`**

Comment: /view?alias_title=network-warringtons-optare-versa-hybrid-yj62fkl-102-1593 if this was passed in it would get 102

Comment: how could i do this regualar expression to be the last instance on - thanks for this big help it is

Comment: It will get the last group of digits following a dash, so you shouldn't worry, it will only catch the last group (1593 in your previous comment). Btw don't forget to trim the URL before using this.

Comment: in php -     preg_match('~(?<=-)\d+~', $alias_title, $id_no_char );
        if (!empty($id_no_char)) {
            $id = intval($id_no_char);
        } this returns 102 in above example

Comment: smae with trim -       preg_match('~(?<=-)\d+~', trim($alias_title), $id_no_char );
        if (!empty($id_no_char)) {
            $id = intval($id_no_char);
        }
        if($id ===0){
            return;
        }

Comment: @MatthewChambers You are forgetting the dollar sign in the pattern. Why did you get rid of it at first place?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `explode()`:

```
$chunks = explode("-", $url);
$numbers = end($chunks);
```

Or a regex like this:

```
/-(\d+)$/
```

Comment: on replace if you check this online http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm regex wont work

Comment: opted for    preg_match('/[^\-]*$/', $alias_title, $matches);       
        $id_no_char = preg_replace('/([^0-9]+)/', '', end($matches));